# VBA find value: how to find cell with only X value and nothing else in it?

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for some assistance, I'm sure this is an easy fix but I can't get my head around how to google for it!

Basically, I am searching for a value in another sheet (this is part of a loop):

```
XYZ = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("a1").Activate
Cells.Find(What:=XYZ, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

However, I have two source values that "overlap", eg: one cell is "Capability" and the other is "Capability Category".

When the macro reaches "Capability" as the look up value, it is finding the cell in with "Capability Category" in the data being searched and applies the action to that instead.

Is there a way I can tell it to look for a cell value that is an exact match, instead of any cell that contains the search term?
(Noting, I cannot re-name any source data or utilise helper columns in this particular workbook.)

Thanks
L

Comment: `Lookat:=xlwhole` perhaps?

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!!
I knew it would be super simple, it was just a really difficult issue to google for.

Comment: Try `...LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole ...`. You need to get rid of `Select`, `Activate`, and `ActiveCell`. Why don't you share the complete code?